# Is there any plain to replace DI implementation in Guice with dagger2

Tags: dependency-injection, cdi, guice, dagger-2

I like dagger2 a lot and want to use it in my new project. The only gotcha is with dagger2 we still have to write some boilerplate code and its missing support for CDI.
Since Google is developing and maintaining dagger2 and also using it for their Android development, I am wondering if they are thinking of replacing the DI implementation in Guice with dagger2, which is my first question.
If they are, then I can start using guice expecting that with some future update I will get the goodness of dagger.
But if they are not, is there a way that I can use both in the same project where guice can be limited to CDI.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Dagger expert, but I'll try to answer your question... (and I hope to do it well)

> I am wondering if they are thinking of replacing the DI implementation in Guice with dagger2,

Nope. There is no good reason to do it. Dagger and Guice present totally different approach to the Dependency Injection concept. The former uses a code generation, the latter - runtime reflection.

> (...) is there a way that I can use both in the same project where guice can be limited to CDI?

I don't think it's a good idea to mix CDI, Dagger and Guice in the same project. Beside fact, that CDI is only a specification, not an actual implementation like Weld or OpenWebBeans - so I guess you wanted to say "DI"?.
Anyway: there is `dagger-adapter extension` which allows using Dagger2 modules with Guice (using [DaggerAdapter](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/daggeradapter/DaggerAdapter.html)) if you really want to mix Dagger with Guice 4.

---

By the way, I would like to give you an idea of what Dagger is and what *it never will be*. Below is a quote from Christian Gruber (who worked on Dagger) on this subject:

> Guice **will always have** a superset of features compared to Dagger, though we do have projects using Dagger on the server and in stand-alone java apps. But Dagger is not as evolved in terms of the surrounding "scaffolding" code (servlet support, etc.) as Guice, and won’t be for quite some time. Additionally, some teams will need or want some advanced Guice features that will never make it in to Dagger.

You may ask what are these "advanced features"? It is e.g. AOP support, like intercepting methods, which might be crucial for many developers.

You can read the whole discussion (February 2014) which is available [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/1y9e6t/ama_were_the_google_team_behind_guava_dagger).

Comment: There is no good reason to do it. --- Better Performance, cleaner stacktrace are few reasons I can think of.

so I guess you wanted to say "DI --- Actually I mean complete DI support with no boiler plate. When I mention CDI I mostly was referi ng to container lifecycle support.

Comment: I think we should always adjust the tools choice to our requirements. You said `Better performance` - but does your app really need those extra few milliseconds? (it might happen on Android, but on the server side?).  **To conclude:** IMHO I think that it's good to have a choice among two such good tools. And I don't see any reason in `(...) replacing the DI implementation in Guice with dagger2`.

Comment: May be you misunderstood me. By no means I am suggesting or expecting that Dagger2 will replace Guice. They both are excellent tools may be for different kind of applications. What I mean is replacing just the underline DI implementation of Guice. It based on reflection which is expensive and by replacing it using compile time code generation as in Dagger2 it can be made faster.

Comment: No, I got your point clearly from the start - my orig answer was referring to it. BTW: Who has told you that reflection is something bad? It has its strengths and weaknesses - and Guice leverages them.

Comment: Arey there any limitations to using DaggerAdapter inside the Guice when you don't have control over say a library already providing Dagger Module?

Answer (score 0):

As someone working on Java application framework development at Google, I can assure you that Google has large important projects built both with Guice and with Dagger, and both DI systems will continue to be used and developed for the foreseeable future.

My personal idea (which is not an official Google plan or statement) is that over time we will build **both** more powerful abstractions on top of Dagger (likely in add-on frameworks and/or libraries) so that Dagger continues to become suitable for a larger and larger set of applications, **and also** more powerful tooling around Guice to make the Guice developer experience become more and more comparable to the Dagger developer experience, at least for a subset of Guice applications that are doing "normal" things.

Both Dagger and Guice are useful tools, each with a different set of trade-offs and a different target audience. Using both in the same project is something that should be possible, although that isn't really the ideal solution because then you can't fully take advantage of the strengths of either of them. But better interoperability is a goal, and the Guice and Dagger teams regularly communicate about how to standardize and coordinate efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this after having issues with Guice and Java 11.  As we barely use guice anyway, I intend to rip it out in favor of dagger for now. Guice is giving me a mega complicated asm based exception that is buried, hard to get a RCA read on and apparently not addressed by the framework. I also, having stepped through the guice code trying to figure this out over a week or so, find the "scaffolding" to be too much for at least my use case and it has me questioning the merits of DI frameworks generally. Dagger2 at least operates at compile time.